# Why won't the modal launch when icon is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I have been trying all sorts of ways to activate the modal from javascript to directly calling the modal to no success. All the page would do is allow a click and then do nothing.

I have tried calling modal from a javascript file,
I have tried directly calling it from the div,
I have tried href the javascript,
I have tried checking for syntax or spelling errors,
and I have tried swapping between div, ancor, image and button tags.

```
<div class="child flex-child">
    <div class="profile-btn">
        <div class="profile-bubble-parent" data-target="#profileModal" data-toggle="modal" onclick="openProfileModal();" > 
            <img class="profile-bubble" src="assets/img/user.ico">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="profileModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="profileModal" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1 class="title-pen"> User Profile <span>UI</span></h1>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="user-profile">
                                <img class="avatar" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTF_erFD1SeUnxEpvFjzBCCDxLvf-wlh9ZuPMqi02qGnyyBtPWdE-3KoH3s" alt="Ash" />
                                <div class="username">
                                    Will Smith
                                </div>
                                <div class="bio">
                                    Senior UI Designer
                                </div>
                                <div class="description">
                                    I use to design websites and applications
                                    for the web.
                                </div>
                                <ul class="data">
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="entypo-heart"> 127</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="entypo-eye"> 853</span>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <span class="entypo-user"> 311</span>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js file has:

```
function openProfileModal(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#profileModal').modal('show');    
    }, 230);

}
```

CSS:

```
/*===================================================================================
======================================PROFILE========================================*/

.profile-bubble {
  height: 55px;
  width: 55px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.title-pen {
  color: #333;
  font-family: "Coda", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.title-pen span {
  color: #55acee;
}

.user-profile {
  margin: auto;
    width: 25em; 
  height: 11em;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: .3em;
}

.user-profile  .username {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -4.40em;
  margin-left: 5.80em;
  color: #658585;
  font-size: 1.53em;
  font-family: "Coda", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.user-profile  .bio {
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10.43em;
  color: #e76043; 
  font-size: .87em;
  font-family: "varela round", sans-serif;
}
.user-profile > .description {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 1.35em;
  margin-right: 4.43em;
  width: 14em;
  color: #c0c5c5; 
  font-size: .87em;
  font-family: "varela round", sans-serif;
}
.user-profile > img.avatar {
    padding: .7em;
  margin-left: .3em;
  margin-top: .3em;
  height: 6.23em;
  width: 6.23em;
  border-radius: 18em;
}

.user-profile ul.data {
    margin: 2em auto;
    height: 3.70em;
  background: #4eb6b6;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0 0 .3em .3em;
}
.user-profile li {
    margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1.30em; 
  width: 33.33334%;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

.user-profile span {
    font-family: "varela round", sans-serif;
    color: #e3eeee;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 1.27em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.user-profile span:hover {
  color: #daebea;
}

/*===================================================================================
======================================MODAL========================================*/

.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Results should be a pop-up modal of the content.

Comment: Where is the "openProfileModal" function defined?

Comment: Without showing your modal event listener and css it will difficult helping you. But quick check. is your modal position as fixed, try setting a higher a z-index on the modal container, check that the left, right, top, and bottom position of your modal is not off the viewport

Comment: @TomErikStøwer I added it to the edit

Comment: @NdifrekeEkim I added it

Comment: Are you using a jquery plugin? How are you loading jquery (and the plugin)? How are you loading your JS?

Comment: @TomErikStøwer jquery no but js using <script  src="assets/js/profile.js"></script>

Comment: Your code looks very much like jquery, but I don't think "modal" is part of the standard library. You can't use jquery without loading it into the browser though. And if you intend to use jquery-modal, you must load that too.

Comment: @TomErikStøwer ok but how do i get modal to work without it? my intention is just a popup... that's all im trying to accomplish

Comment: It depends a bit on your CSS frankly. But you should learn how to access DOM nodes using document selectors if you don't intend to use jquery. For example, to get the DOM node with id "profileModal", you can use document.getElementById('profileModal'). You can then manipulate the css/style properties of that DOM element.

Comment: @TomErikStøwer ok let me try that, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I moved the modal body outside the   tag and gave it an id, profileModal.
Next, thing I knew it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't intend to use jquery, use the Document API to access the HTMLElement node , and then manipulate the style properties on it.

```
var modal = document.getElementById('profileModal');
modal.style.display = 'block';
```

Since I don't know the exact nature of your CSS, it's difficult to give a more precise answer.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Comment: it's not working but thanks. It at least helped me get closer to the problem

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't expect it to work. Like I said, depends on your CSS, and without knowing more about it, I can't give the exact answer. I think it probably answers your question though.

Comment: I added the CSS to the question